# Sending JSON object to API by using http post

Tags: android, http-headers, http-post

I want to add header "Content-Type" "application/json". But I am not been able to do this due to api 23 in android.

```
                OutputStream os= null;
                os=httpclient.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

                JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                jsonobj.put("Name","alpha");
                jsonobj.put("Status","Active");
                jsonobj.put("Type","Admin");
                jsonobj.put("Address","beta");
                jsonobj.put("Password","333");
                jsonobj.put("PhoneNumber",123);

                bw.write(jsonobj.toString());
                os.close();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to make a network call to some `API` which expects you to add `Headers` to the `HTTP` calls you are making and the `content-type` data is `JSON`.

If that is your case then you would have to specify the Headers to the instance to respective class with which you are trying to connect..

for example if you are using `HttpURLConnection`
then it would look like this

```
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // hear you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json` 
            httpURLConnection.connect();
```

and when you are posting some data to the instance of the `HttpURLConnection` you can do it like this...

```
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("para_1", "arg_1");
            jsonObject.addProperty("para_2", "arg_2");

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
```