# Android HTTP Post- send Json Parameters without double quotes

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to send Json Parameters (below) in Android - POST Method.

```
{"message":"This is venkatesh","visit":[5,1,2]}
```

I tried the below code

```
                String IDs="5,1,2";
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("message", "This is venkatesh");

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                jsonArray.put(IDs);
                jsonObject.put("visit", jsonArray);
                String json = jsonObject.toString();
                Log.d("Mainactivity", " json" + json);
```

I am getting the output is

```
{"message":"This is venkatesh","visit":["5,1,2"]}
 // Output i am get with double quotes inside visit


{"message":"This is venkatesh","visit":[5,1,2]}
// I want to send this parameter without Double quotes inside the Visit
```

Comment: see here for more help http://stackoverflow.com/a/18563298/5202007

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702689/sending-jason-object-to-api-by-using-http-post/34702773#34702773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String IDs="5,1,2";
String[] numbers = IDs.split(",");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++)
{
    jsonArray.put(Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In array add it as integer not as a String

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("message", "This is venkatesh");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonArray.put(5);
            jsonArray.put(1);
            jsonArray.put(2);
            jsonObject.put("visit", jsonArray);
            String json = jsonObject.toString();
            Log.i("TAG", " json" + json); //{"message":"This is venkatesh","visit":[5,1,2]}

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace following line:

`jsonArray.put(IDs);`

with following code:

```
jsonArray.put(5);
jsonArray.put(1);
jsonArray.put(2);
```

So you should use 'int' values if you want to see array without quotes. The point is 'quotes' means that this is String object. Proof is following line of your code:

`String IDs="5,1,2";`

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("message", "This is venkatesh"); 
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new int[](5, 1, 2)); 
jsonObject.put("visit", jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you will convert the String to integer array and after you do this is how you can add,

Well the only difference you need to understand is that, `JSON` adds double quotes for values of `String` and not of `Integer`.

so for Key value pair for `String` it would be

```
"key":"value"
```

so for Key value pair for `Integer` it would be

```
"key":123
```

so for Key value pair for `boolean` it would be

```
"key":true
```

With that knowledge you can edit your code.

> Code

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("message", "This is venkatesh");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(0,5);
        jsonArray.put(1,1);
        jsonArray.put(2,2);
        jsonObject.put("visit", jsonArray);

        Log.d("TAG","result "+jsonObject.toString());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> Output

```
{"message":"This is venkatesh","visit":[5,1,2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arrayOfInteger=[1,2,3];

JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
jsonObject .put("message","your message");

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arrayOfInteger);
jsonObject .put("visit",jsonArray );
```

Result : `{"message":"your message","visit":[1,2,3]}`